# Postfix is timed out while sending

Tags: firewall, postfix, smtp

I have just set up postfix (with tasksel install mail-server) with the default settings. Unfortunately, I can not send e-mails from by SMTP server.

Here is my main.cf:

```
# See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version
# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
#myorigin = /etc/mailname

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = mydomain.tld
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = mydomain.tld, PC-01, localhost.localdomain, localhost
relayhost = 
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_command = procmail -a "$EXTENSION"
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
```

Where mydomain.tld is my domain (surprise, surprise...).

I have checked /var/log/mail.log and it's keep saying:

```
Jun 16 20:38:59 PC-01 postfix/smtp[12967]: connect to mta5.am0.yahoodns.net[66.196.118.37]:25: Connection timed out
```

I have also googled the whole night about this problem and others said it could be caused by the ISP since they are blocking port 25. I have checked it online, but I think they are not. (How can I make sure?)

So I would be greatful if you could help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you get SMTP greeting mesage from a remote mail server?

```
telnet 66.196.118.37 25
```

You may use tcptraceroute to locate the firewall blocking SMTP connections.

[`man tcptraceroute`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/tcptraceroute.1.html)

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

I have tried out telnet earlier (and now once again) but it keeps time out.

Same with tcptraceroute:
`root@ubuntu:/home/thomas# tcptraceroute 66.196.118.37
traceroute to 66.196.118.37 (66.196.118.37), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  * * *
[...]
15  * * *
16  mta-v5.mail.vip.bf1.yahoo.com (66.196.118.37) <rst,ack>  300.182 ms mta-v5.mail.vip.bf1.yahoo.com (66.196.118.37) <rst,ack,cwr>  300.141 ms  300.240 ms`

and tried out with port 25 (tcptraceroute 66.196.118.37 25), but that time it did not write line started with "mta-v5" like before.